# Android: No such column

Tags: android, database, runtimeexception

Here´s my log-file:

```
05-04 09:29:10.968: E/SQLiteLog(26491): (1) no such column: datum
05-04 09:29:10.968: D/AndroidRuntime(26491): Shutting down VM
05-04 09:29:10.968: W/dalvikvm(26491): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40edc930)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unserekinder/com.example.unserekinder.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: datum (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, datum, geschlecht FROM kind
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: datum (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT name, datum, geschlecht FROM kind
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at com.example.unserekinder.DBHelper.select(DBHelper.java:80)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at com.example.unserekinder.MainActivity.listview_fuellen(MainActivity.java:52)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at com.example.unserekinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-04 09:29:10.976: E/AndroidRuntime(26491):    ... 11 more
```

I read a few other questions about this problem but nothing helped me. 
It seems to me that just this one column isn´t created.

```
private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "unserekinder.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public static final String id = "_id";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_Kind="kind";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String DATUM = "datum";
    public static final String GESCHLECHT = "geschlecht";

    private static final String TABLE_KIND_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Kind + " (" + id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    + NAME + " TEXT, " + DATUM + " TEXT, " + GESCHLECHT + " TEXT);";



    public static final String TABLE_KIND_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kind";
    public static final String TABLE_KIND_DELETE = "DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS kind";       

    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_KIND_CREATE);

    }
```

You see, the statement must be executed because it is in `onCreate`.

Here is my select statement:

```
public void insert( String name, String datum, String geschlecht){
        long rowId = -1;
        try{

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(NAME, name);
            cv.put(DATUM, datum);
            cv.put(GESCHLECHT, geschlecht);

            rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_Kind, null, cv);
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "insert()", e);
        }
        finally{
            Log.d(TAG, "insert(): rowId=" + rowId);
        }
    }

    public void create(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(TABLE_KIND_CREATE);
    }

    public Cursor select(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_Kind, new String[] {"name", "datum", "geschlecht"}, 
                "" + "", null, null, null, null);
        db.endTransaction();
        return cursor;
    }
```

**edit:**

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrade der Datenbank von Version " + oldVersion + "zu " +newVersion+ "; alle Daten werden gelöscht");
    db.execSQL(TABLE_KIND_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: is it successfully executing, when you remove `datum` from the selection?

Comment: When I try this, the application starts but when I insert into my database, the same error occurs.

Comment: It seems your table is created without datum, field try to change the version of database and I don't to onupgrade method in your dbhelper, I think you may not have posted it.

Comment: I´ve seen that the cursor size is 0, also after inserting something. Any idea why?

Comment: @user896692 You might have added datum column later and you might be trying to reexecute the same program. Instead you uninstall the app from you emulator or device completely and then run it again. If you still don't get it post back.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_Kind, new String[] {"name", "datum", "geschlecht"}, 
                "" + "", null, null, null, null);
The query is wrong.
What do you mean by following code?
 "" + ""
You can change ""+"" to null.Try it.